# Github pages (gh-Pages) img resource not/found/wont load?

Tags: github-pages

I am using github pages and the index.html opens and the css and javascript loads but the images wont, I look at the path http://myusername.github.com/project-name/img/example.png and example.png will load after view raw, I tried to commit the images seperately but no changes were detected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the path is case sensitive...png is not the same as PNG.
What is the path to your repo?

Answer (score 1):

You can use base href path end separator from your url repository

Example:

https://github.com/YourName/Repo/ # "/" End Line Separator

Include Image File Path To { img/img.jpg } # With your link